# What parameters are missing in the Query record for Yahoo Finance API in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery, yahoo-finance

The following Yahoo Finance API endpoint recently stopped working when I called it using the Web.Contents connector from Power Query. The result of calling this API appoint from Power Query is that I am being prompted to define the type of access to the API endpoint.

```
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=<Ticker>
```

[Authentication issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51OsO.png)

If the API endpoint is modified and the Crumb Value is added to the relative path

```
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=<Ticker?&crumb=<Crumb-value>
```

This HTTPS returns a JSON document in any web browser,

[JSON response in Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1ufI.png)

While when running the same web link using Power Query, we are prompted to define again the Type of Connection

My Question: Besides the Crumb what else I am missing that is required in the Query record so when added in Power Query. What parameters should be pass to the Headers record

Appreciated any help on the topic.

Try directly the API point in Power Query with the crumb obtained using:

```
"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb"
```

We will have expected to see a JSON file but instead we are prompted to add Credentials. When clicked in anonymous and error is raised and cannot continue the operation

[Error when credentials update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSb98.png)

Comment: Probably the user agent. This issue has been discussed before, e.g., here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68657740/1024832

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yahoo finance API gives error 403 (forbidden) on old URL and User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657671/yahoo-finance-api-gives-error-403-forbidden-on-old-url-and-user-agent)

Comment: @Luke_0 - thanks. The link provided does not answer the question. I do not get a 403 error. Simply when I use the Web.Contents function of powerquery I get prompted to this message (see image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSb98.png)  )

Comment: Does Yahoo finance require an API key?

Comment: @Luke_0 -> I believe that is not the case as the API can be accessed with no problem from the web browsers whenever the end point includes the crumb. What i still do not understand is why the web address works in the web browser but then when using the Power Query web data connector it asks for login credentials

Answer (score 0):

Since earlier this year, yahoo finance needs a cookie, and a crumb, and it automatically rejects calls from undefined clients, that's why your browser works, but some other apps don't.

In order to make it work, you need to have a user agent in the get request header to simulate a browser. Also, you need a cookie allocated to you, which doesn't happen when calling the query servers. Best way I found to do this is through a macro.

1 -> make a get request, with a user agent string in the header, to any yahoo.com webpage. In the response header, look for "Set-Cookie" to check that you've been sent a cookie, and save it.

2 -> make another get request, using the cookie string you've received previously, in the header to the getcrumb url. Save the crumb.

3 -> make your quote call , adding the crumb

I don't know if it's possible to get this done via powerquery, but it can be done via macros.